# How to keep a dynamic textbox from moving other fields when growing

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-table, field

I hope I can explain the question well enough.  I have a table with a textbox at the bottom.  The users can grab the corner of the box and expand it out if they wish, but in doing so a few other fields move with it.  I am inheriting this page from someone else so I cannot speak to their methodology.  The form is set up as a two column table.  Most of the fields are ion the fist column.  Aside from the textbox in question, there is only one other textbox that spans both columns, but it is a single line and cannot expand.  There are only two fields that are totally in the second column only. These two move when the dynamic textbox gets expanded.  I tried setting a width on the two fields that are moving since they did not have one and hoped it would fix it, but it did not.  This is being written in C# ASP.NET.

Code for the fields and textbox:

```
<td style="width: 140px;">
<label for="txtLastName" id="Label2" style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;"><span style="color: #FF0000">*</span>Last Name:</label></td>

<td>
<asp:TextBox CssClass="textbox" ID="txtLastName" runat="server" TabIndex="2" 
    Height="19px" Width="130px"></asp:TextBox></td>



<td colspan="2">
<asp:TextBox CssClass="textbox" ID="txtComments" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" 
   TabIndex="6" Height="30px" Width="275px"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

I am sorry if this is too much information, but I assume this is a simple fix that I am overlooking, I am new to development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy thing to do is in the CSS for that textarea do the following:

textarea{resize:none; height:120px; max-height:120px; min-height:120px;}

this will do the trick - you don't need the min and max although I put it in just to be safe!

hope this helps!

Comment: Would that keep the box from growing?  I want the users to be able to grab the box and expand it if they want, I just don;t want the LastName label and textbox to go with it.  I will do as you suggest and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: Hi Peter - sorry may have read question wrong - this will stop the box from being grabbed and stretched by the end user - will just re-read your question and reply

Comment: Peter do you have a link I could view?

Comment: It is on USA800.com at the bottom of the home page.  I hope I am not breaking any rules of this site by posting this kind of link, but I am just stuck on what to do.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: if not doable for you then just set max-width to stop people stretching it out but allows them to extend it down

Comment: Simple answer indeed.  I just took the textbox out of the table and it worked perfectly.  Thanks for you help!